# How to update tester feedback in Firebase Distribution?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I implemented Firebase Distribution in my app. It working well. But during testing how the tester will update the feedback. There is no feature in the tester app. In the Firebase documentation, they mentioned tester can share the feedback.

[image: Firebase Image]

Comment: Before downvote please explain why. It will be more helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no option for tester feedback in firebase app distribution.**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Update: Firebase App Distribution supports in-app feedback for Android**

With the App Distribution Android SDK you can collect feedback from testers directly from your app. You can then view the feedback in the Firebase console or have it sent to third party tools using Cloud Functions.

See the [setup guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/collect-feedback-from-testers) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Testers can see developer's email address from console or invitation emails. And emailing the developer would be the way they give feedbacks.